# How to access pdf files without having the .pdf using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to access the pdf files but without the `filename.pdf`  only `filename`

How can I do this using htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following Rule in `root/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.pdf [L]
```

This will internally redirect `/filename` to `/filename.pdf`